# Set UIWebView keyboardAppearance to UIKeyboardAppearanceDark

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiwebview, keyboard

I'm creating an app that needs to display the darker keyboard (UIKeyboardAppearanceDark) in iOS7 for a UIWebView text field.

Basically, I'm posting a video to Facebook (using [ESSVideoShare](https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion/wiki/How-To-for-iOS)), by logging in through a web view Facebook login page. And for the keyboard that appears when you touch the WebView is the default white keyboard in iOS7. I would like to change this to be the darker keyboard to keep the theme of the app consistent.

I managed to do this for the UITextFields by doing :

```
editableTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

But I wasn't able to find a way to access the keyboard or appearance properties of UIWebView.

This app is not going into the app store and thus I can use private APIs, if there are no public API available to achieve this.

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this and use this method in ViewWillAppear so appearance can be set before view is loading.

```
 [[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];
```

Answer (score 0):

make UIWebBrowserView implement keyboardAppearance method

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not provide any property in UIWebView class to make keyboard appearance dark in UIWebView.
You may like to make background colour of keyboard dark which you can accomplish by adding a subview behind keyboard that shows and hide with keyboard appearance.

The https://github.com/meekapps/TintedKeyboard has the library which does this.